# ImportError: No module named Processing

Tags: python, importerror, qgis

ImportError:  No module named Processing

I am using QGIS APIs for developing my application in Python. Eclipse is the IDE that I have been using for other projects. Now, I am trying to connect eclipse to the packages and libraries of QGIS but it is not going well.
the error I currently get is:

ImportError:  No module named Processing

I have included all libraries, packages, DLLs and so on.

[image]

below you can see a snapshot of a piece of my code.

[image]

I have no idea how to fix it.
I have checked this [configuration](http://geographicprimitive.wordpress.com/2010/09/04/setting-up-pyqgis-development-environment-with-pydev-on-windows/#comment-18) as well.

I also read almost all the related topics in the stackoverflow...I set the processing in my python path (both in the beginning and at the end)..
I have been restarting my system every time I changed the setting...
what is wrong!

Comment: Have you tried the suggestions here?: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/74096/using-the-processing-framework-in-qgis-2-0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To work with processing package, you should add it in a level higher than processing package like:

```
C:\OSGeo4W\apps\qgis\python\plugins
```

where processing is in plugins. then import processing will perfectly work.